# Hosting a React app inside Express returns ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react app, created using `create-react-app`, I'd like to use an express app to host it.

I have written an express app as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'))
app.use(
  express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    { index: false,
      fallthrough: true,
      setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.size && /\.\w{8}(\.chunk)?\.(js|css)$/.test(path)) {
          res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
        } else if (stat && stat.size && /service-worker\.js$/.test(path)) {
          res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, max-age=0')
        }
      }
    }
  )
)

app.get('/healthz', (_, res) => {
  res.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0')
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.get('*', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'))
})

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000)
}

module.exports = app
```

I build my app using `"build": "react-scripts build",` which puts the output in a build folder. When I try and host the app however I see the following in Chrome:

[image]

My app is structured as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add "/" to you routing and use path.join to send builded file to Clint.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'))
app.use(
  express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    { index: false,
      fallthrough: true,
      setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.size && /\.\w{8}(\.chunk)?\.(js|css)$/.test(path)) {
          res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
        } else if (stat && stat.size && /service-worker\.js$/.test(path)) {
          res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, max-age=0')
        }
      }
    }
  )
)

app.get('/healthz', (_, res) => {
  res.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0')
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.get('/*', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'...','build/index.html'))
})

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000)
}

module.exports = app
```